# Cannot get Android project to launch automatically

Tags: java, android, boot

There are lots of posts on this, but I have not been able to get my app to auto-start on boot.
Set up.
I have an Android Galaxy Tab S6 Lite.
I performed a factory reset.
In Android Studio, I created a new Java application with one main activity, which just displays some text.
Then, after reading a few posts on this I did the following:

I created a StartActivityOnBootReceiver class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class StartActivityOnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And in the manifest, I added:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And:

```
        <receiver android:name=".StartActivityOnBootReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I ran the app on the tablet, stopped it, then power cycled the device.
The app did not launch automatically.

Note: I eventually want this app to run (and auto-start) on different hardware, that will be running Android 9.0 (Pie), so I specified this when creating the project.
Here is my gradle.build (I had to paste an image of it because stackoverflow wouldn't format the code correctly):

[image]

Can anyone suggest any further steps to take?

Thanks

Comment: Add logging in `onReceive()` so that you can determine if the boot receiver is being called. Generally launching an `Activity` from a background process (`Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc. ) is no longer permitted. You should scan the logcat and see if there are any error messages coming from the Android system complaining about why your `Activity` is not launched.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts for the new rules about launching activities from background processes. However, these new rules are as of Android 10. You wrote that your app should be running on a device that has Android 9 installed. Therefore you may not have this problem on your target device. You should check if your code works on your target device and/or on an emulator running Android 9.

Comment: Also, if you have a single-purpose device that will only be running your app, you might want to consider writing your app as a HOME-screen replacement (basically putting the device in "Kiosk mode"). In this case, Android would launch your app on boot instead of the standard HOME screen.

Comment: @David Wasser, can you point me in a good direction to set up the app as a HOME-screen replacement please?

Comment: Have a look here, there is information and links about various ways to deal with single-purpose devices: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices